# VB.Net Using RegEx or another method to Extract code between curly braces

Tags: json, regex, vb.net

I have a batch file that returns a block of code with every run.  The block of code is always different depending on a few factors.

I want to isolate the hex code only and have it displayed in a text box.

At the end of this code, it states:

`"keys": [{"key": "293c71efrfh646q6b22f073q04ee9668:42c4e2866aceedc75a253c02b02eb6f0"}]}]`

The hexadecimal code in between the brackets/curly braces is always going to change, but the keys/key/brackets are always static.

The entire returned code block is:

```
[{"lidents": "https://maniboss.sock.boltend.net/Lidents/v1/geng/hidemime/6074092009001/aca60971-b391-4d9f-8280-cd62615f086d1/192b71cf-bfa6-46c6-a22f-073d04ee9668?nastly_token=NjFkZThhMTlfNGM4YjI5MGY5MDgxZDhkMmUxMWNkYTllOTlkM2RmOTYxNTNlNWM5YTQwNThiNzEyNTA0NmM3ZTE1OTVmN2VkNA%3D%3D", "ship": "QQQRVnBzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAADYIARIQGTtxz7+mRsaiLwc9BO6WaBoNd2lkZXZpbmVfdGVzdCIIMTIzNDU2NzgyB2RlZmF1bHQ=", "proxy": {}, "headers": {"Connection": "close", "User-Agent": "LURL/7.55.1", "Accept": "*/*", ""Referer": "https://www.shunted.com/tray/b14d73db00f952be"", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "X-Request-Id": "c6217f1d-da21-3563-aec4-4fd62fd5fd64", "X-Forwarded-For": "23.15.04.215", "X-Forwarded-Proto": "http", "X-Forwarded-Port": "80", "Via": "1.1 vegur", "Connect-Time": "0", "X-Request-Start": "1631923413180", "Total-Route-Time": "0", "Content-Length": "000"}, "time": "03:08:33", "keys": [{"key": "293c71efrfh646q6b22f073q04ee9668:42c4e2866aceedc75a253c02b02eb6f0"}]}]
```

I've been struggling with regex, but found a solution on regex101.com that will successfully show just the hex code I want.  The code for that is:  `(?<=\{"key": ").*?(?=\"})`

This only highlights the code and nothing else, but when I plug that into my vb.net app, I get all kinds of errors in regards to the quotations.  Do I need to even use this?

Is there an easier way to highlight the hex code at the bottom and put it in a text box as an output since I know it's position will always be the same?

Thanks

Comment: Why regex a string? You should simply deserialize that JSON. Event though it's malformed. Is this the real thing or did you edit it somehow?

Comment: Malformed means there are double double-quotes around the `Referer` property, which makes it invalid. -- You can use the [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/) service to generate .Net classes in VB.Net.

Comment: There are 2 quotes before Referer and then 2 quotes after the URL ends, is that still considered malformed.  Wouldn't regex be simpler than converting the entire JSON code into .NET?

Comment: Yes, that makes it a malformed JSON. -- No, it's not. Once you have generated a simple Model that describes the JSON (and this a very simple structure) , it's done forever. One command and you get whatever value or, as in this case, array of values (since the property you're trying to read can be an array of `keys`, not just a single key).

Comment: I'm not trying to get an array of keys.  The keys all generate in the same area and are the same length.  It's always 65 characters.  I just want the key to appear in a read only text box when the application is done.  I don't understand why programming in general is so complicated I can't do a simple task like Set Point A = This, Set Point B = That, Copy content between point a & b into text box.

Comment: Try `(?<=\{\"key\": \").*?(?=\"})` if you want to use RegEx.